# BroadCasting

Tags: broadcasting

Ok in order to broadcast, I have created a socket:

```
 notifySock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
```

And to send the hostname of my computer to all other computers connected to the same lan, I am using the send(Byte[] buffer) method:

```
 notifySock.Send(hostBuffer);
```

hostBuffer contains the hostname of my computer.

However because I am using a 'datagram' socket-type do I need to format the data I need to send.
If possible please provide the code that I must put in between the two lines of code I have entered to create a socket and send the data.

Answer (score 1):

For broadcast from a user application, [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) is typically used. You need to design a suitable protocol, i.e. a way to format the information you want to send into the UDP packet.

Comment: ok I got that. Am using a datagram socketType for which UDP works fine.
I have a small doubt now.
Between creating the socket of type datagram and sending the data, what is the code I need to write to broadcast the message.
Creating an IPEndPoint of type broadcast is fine but how do I use it??

Answer (score 0):

In your example you haven't specified who you are sending to. You need something like:

```
UdpClient notifySock = new UdpClient(endPoint);  
notifySock.Send(buffer, buffer.Length, new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 1234));
```

For the other hosts on your LAN to receive that they have to be listening on UDP port 1234.

Comment: Got that.. The new problem here is that there is a receive method within the UDPClient class.. However one of its parameters is a reference variable of type IPEndPoint..But if I need to hear a broadcast message, I do not need that..What is the method I must call to receive a broadcasted message.